# How do I install web3@1.0.-beta.26 on Windows 10?

Tags: web3js

How do I install web3@1.0.-beta.26 on Windows 10? `npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.26` does not work and creates a page of errors.

I've also tried --python=python2.7

Here is what I get.

```
C:\Users\user\inbox>npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.26 --python=python2.7
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Users\user\inbox\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Users\user\inbox\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\user\inbox\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
    options.duplicate_basename_check)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 98, in Load
    generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1916, in CalculateVariables
    generator_flags.get('msvs_version', 'auto'))
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 434, in SelectVisualStudioVersion
    versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)
KeyError: '2017'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\inbox\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-17T22_41_28_270Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The problem appears to be you are using VS 2017, I'd suggest to try VS 2015 that version appears to work.

Comment: Tried this and am still getting the errors.

Comment: From the error message about missing a file, it appears something have failed previously, perhaps a download didn't finis correctly. If you have the log file upload it to pastebin or similar and add a link here.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt as Administrator.

Run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

You are missing some of the build tools. Try installing the above package that will fetch the necessary tools and python version.

---

If the above still doesn't work, try starting fresh by deleting existing build tools

> C:\Users\'yourUserName'\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools

### **Open cmd:(Administrator mode)**

RUN
 npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global --production
 windows-build-tools

Make sure npm pointing to the right Python version by running

```
npm config set python python\path\to\executable
```

The 'path' should point directly to the Python.exe

**Note:** When installing windows-build-tools with npm, python executable can be found

> C:\Users\'yourUserName'.windows-build-tools\python27

---

I think the above will resolve the issue and you can RUN `npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.26`

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Node version and then install web3.
Had the same problem and also tried with other things (using VS2015 and installing windows-build-tools and setting up python), but the only thing that helped me was upgrading node to newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late on replying, If you've already tried this:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

and still facing the same problem then take the pain and install **visual studio 2017**, with of course the C++ compiler included.

I was facing the same problem for the long time and did try almost everything internet had to offer like tried updating the `nodejs` and other dependencies of project like  `ganache-cli`, `mocha` but that didn't help. I ended up installing the **vs 2017** and worked like a charm afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015` worked for me. As was stated already you can also install Visual Studio 2015/2017 which I had recently uninstalled vs2017 and I started running into a similar issue once I created a new project with web3.

Answer (score 0):

when i try to unlock my ethereum private network account in geth version 1.10.16, it show error like this.....how could i overcome this..?

GoError: Error: account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden at web3.js:6365:37(47)
at github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/jsre.MakeCallback.func1 (native)
at :1:24(3)