# Error while installing web3

Tags: error, npm

I'm getting these errors while executing

```
npm install web3
```

How could i fix this?

[image: the error output1]

[image: the error output2]

Comment: One of the dependencies requires python version 2.7 (node-gyp). See the documentation in their [repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#configuring-python-dependency) how to configure to select the correct version of python.

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36653/how-do-i-install-web31-0-beta-26-on-windows-10

Comment: You also might need to run `npm init` first or install globally with `-g`

Comment: See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/63586/14035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Python does not match the required version for one of the dependencies. To explain your error in more detail, Python is not compiled, so version mismatch is found at run-time. The program is using the old Python 2.7 print syntax which is flagging the error. By installing the appropriate version of Python 2.7 or upgrading to a version of the library that uses an older version of Python (if there is one), you should be able to resolve this problem.

From the `node-gyp` README at https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp:

[image]